# C++ dependency injection through constructor

Tags: c++

I tried making a simple DI test, where a class `car` is injected with a `container` interface.

It gives an error 'incomplete type', see the comment in the code.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Car;

class IContainer {
public:
    virtual ~IContainer()=default;
};

class Container: public IContainer {
public:
    explicit Container(int i = 1) {
        std::cout << std::to_string(i);
    };

    void makeCar() {
        Car car(this); //Variable has incomplete type 'Car'
    }
};


class Car  {
public:
    explicit Car(IContainer &container): c(container) {
        printf("constructed\n");
    }

private:
    IContainer &c;
};


int main() {

    Container container(5);
    container.makeCar();

    return 0;
}
```

Solution - here's the working modified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Car;

class IContainer {
public:
    virtual ~IContainer()=default;
    virtual void foo(){}
};

class Container: public IContainer {
public:
    explicit Container(int i = 1) {
        std::cout << std::to_string(i) << std::endl;
    };

    void foo() override {
        std::cout << "bar\n";
    }

    void makeCar();

};


class Car  {
public:
    explicit Car(IContainer *container): c(container) {
        printf("Car constructed\n");
        c->foo();
    }

private:
    IContainer *c;
};

void Container::makeCar() {
    //Constructing the car will call a function on the injected container
    Car car(this);
}

int main() {

    Container container(5);
    container.makeCar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to use `Car` before it has a complete declaration.  Put `Container::makeCar` after `Car` declaration.

Comment: @Eljay Make that an answer

Comment: But I'm using forward declaring right? If I move the Car code, then it will not find the container code.

Comment: `this` Is a pointer too

Comment: @Oli: Eljay didn't tell you to move the whole `Container` class, but to move the body of `makeCar` out of the class.  You'll need a function prototype/declaration in the class, with no body.  And a definition after all classes are defined.

Comment: The `Car` code doesn't need the `Container` code. It only needs the `IContainer` code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/HGX5w4e0QN94morn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++ compiler reads your C++ program from beginning to the end, compiling as it goes along. At any point your C++ compiler only knows what it's read so far (we'll ignore some specific exceptions that do not matter here).

```
class Car;
```

Your C++ compiler now knows that your program has a class named `Car`. It doesn't know anything at all about this class. Nothing. Zilch. Nada. Zippo.

```
    void makeCar()
    {
        Car car(this);
    }
```

Now your C++ compiler needs to generate code that creates such a `Car`. That's a problem: your C++ compiler doesn't know anything at all about this class. Nothing. Zilch. Nada. Zippo.

The complete class gets declared later, but your C++ compiler doesn't know anything about it.

The solution is simple: just declare the class method here:

```
    void makeCar();
```

And then later, after `Car` is declared, you can define this class method (just before `main`):

```
void Container::makeCar() {
    Car car(this); // It works!
}
```

Everything else remains the same. Now your C++ compiler is omnipotent, all-knowing, and all-powerful. It knows everything now.